# Display HH:mm:ss in DateTime x axis in Chart C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

I have series of data (temperature vs time) and I want to plot it using `Chart` object of `.NET 4.0.` The problem is that if I choose `DateTime` as the `XValueType` for the series it is displayed like `dd.mm.yyyy` but I want to display it as `HH:mm:ss`.

**How can I do that?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: From MSChar it looks like WinForm

Comment: @Crono, yes you are right

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:**

Try This:

```
DateTime myDateValue = DateTime.Now;
String XValueType  = myDateValue.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

**Solution 2:**

if you are using windows chart control then

Try This:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
```

**Solution 3:** as you said in your below comments if you are showing only DateTime as a string it would be difficult while comparing.

Yes it would be difficult if you only show the `Time` part `(HH:mm:ss)` as string.
but if you display the Date and Time then you can again convert back the string to DateTime and perform conversion.

Try This:

```
DateTime date=DateTime.Now;
axisLabel=date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

you can convert the datetime string back to DateTime as below:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(axisLabel,"dd.MM.yyyy 
                     HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That is what I am using now, but I want to keep it as DateTime because then I need to be able to choose the axis limits and I think that is not possible if the x axis is as string, right?

Comment: @betelgeuse: yes i think if you only show the time in x-axis as a string then it would be a problem while comparing but if you sow complete date and time then you can convert it back to `DateTime` and then compare

Comment: thanks. How would the user then choose the axis limits if the chart doesn't know anything about dates?

Comment: you can convert those strings back to proper `datetime` and perform comparisions.

Comment: are you setting the `XValueType` as `DateTime`?

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Until now I was converting to string the DateTime values before ploting...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48709/discussion-between-sudhakar-tillapudi-and-betelgeuse)

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the culture.info part, what should I enter there?